# How can I remove a Column that has a Constraint with a migration from the DB (ASP.NET MVC5)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Each time I try dropping a column with the following migration:

```
public partial class RemoveProject_Id1InAspNetUsers2 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Project_Id1");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
```

I get the following error after I `Update-Database` in PMC:

```
The index 'IX_Project_Id1' is dependent on column 'Project_Id1'.
The object 'FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.Projects_Project_Id1' is dependent on column 'Project_Id1'.
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN Project_Id1 failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

This is my AspNetUser Table:
[dbo.AspNetUser DB Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGeDS.png)

This is my Project Class:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Project Manager")]
    public string ProjectManagerId { get; set; }

    //        [ForeignKey("ProjectManagerId")]
    //        public ApplicationUser ProjectManager { get; set; }

    //public string ProjectMembersId { get; set; }

    //public List<ApplicationUser> ProjectMembers { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectResource> OurProjectResources { get; set; }

}
```

I have tried removing removing all references of ApplicationUser from my Project Class.

PS: I've tried running a Migration of this SQL statement: 
`Sql("ALTER TABLE AspNetUsers DROP CONSTRAINT FK_AspNetUsers_Projects_Project_Id1");` and it gives an error that :

```
'FK_AspNetUsers_Projects_Project_Id1' is not a constraint.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

I'm using EF6 Code First Workflow.

[This post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6bb05268-946a-4607-8793-dfd60c468974/drop-column-not-working-one-or-more-objects-access-this-column?forum=sqlexpress) explains what the problem is, but I will like to understand how to write the migration to remove the column from the DB.

Comment: Try this `Sql("ALTER TABLE AspNetUsers DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.Projects_Project_Id1]");`

Comment: @gotqn, migration ran and when I believe the constraint was removed but when I tried removing the column again with `DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Project_Id1");`, the error I get is: `The index 'IX_Project_Id1' is dependent on column 'Project_Id1'.
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN Project_Id1 failed because one or more objects access this column.` Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to specify the constraint name as it is in the error:

> 'FK_AspNetUsers_Projects_Project_Id1' is not a constraint. Could not
>   drop constraint. See previous errors.

So, to drop the constraint, we can use:

```
Sql("ALTER TABLE AspNetUsers DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.Projects_Project_Id1]");
```

Then, you get error, that there is an index created on the field:

> The index 'IX_Project_Id1' is dependent on column 'Project_Id1'. ALTER
>   TABLE DROP COLUMN Project_Id1 failed because one or more objects
>   access this column.

We need to drop the index, too.

```
Sql("DROP INDEX [IX_Project_Id1] ON dbo.AspNetUsers ");
```